# How to delete all records in measurement except last record in InfluxDB?

Tags: sql, database, influxdb

I searched for answer all day and found influxdb hasn't '''IN''' like SQL.
so can influxdb do like

```
DELETE  
FROM tablename 
WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM tablename order by column1 desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
```

I have no idea.

Comment: Standard SQL subselect doesn't work in the InfluxDB. Also tables and columns don't exist (but measurement and fields). IMHO the best option is here is to use LAST selector, which will give you last datapoint time, which can be used then in the DELETE query.

Answer (score 0):

Everything possible with InfluxQL is specified [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/). InfluxQL does not support IN operator currently.

This is one of the approaches may help you to solve your issue:

- Copy the latest record to a file
- Delete records from measurement
- Insert back to the measurement from the saved file

**EDIT**

As [@Nikolay Manolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9193254/nikolay-manolov) mentioned in comment, you can find the timestamp of latest record and delete everything that is older than that.

Comment: How about get the latest record, get the timestamp, delete everything that is older than that? No need to save and re-insert a record.

Comment: @Nikolay That is even better than what I have mentioned here. Write an answer, I will delete my answer